# What are the best attack combos to use in Magicka in early game and what are they?

Tags: magicka

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most powerful beam spell variant?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16294/most-powerful-beam-spell-variant)

What are the best attack combos to use in Magicka in early game and what are they?
Because at the moment it is just random attacks and alchemy+electricty.
What are the other suggestions?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/what-is-the-most-powerful-non-beam-spell-in-magicka

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16294/most-powerful-beam-spell-variant

Comment: As you have access to all of the elements at the end of the tutorial, the two links provided by yx_ should be of interest to you.

Comment: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1733437

Comment: all of the above answers are really very good. yx_ you did a good job. :)

Comment: Once you have all elements there is no difference between early and late game, use the combos yx_ recommended.